# A better way of saying "inventions are invented"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, synonyms

> *“It is a great privilege to be born in the century of innovation. This is a time when revolutionary inventions are invented daily.”*

I need alternatives, but I've already used "created" as a word, don't really want to substitute any other synonym in.

Or does it not sound bad at all as it is?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I've gotten a lot of criticism for my question since people say I could just look at a thesaurus. I wasn't clear enough, it's my fault. I'm not really looking for words to replace *"invented"*, I'm looking for an alternative way of writing the same sentence, to get the same meaning across.

Gwendolyn understood what I was asking from her comment: *“inventions are invented” is redundant. I would consider re-wording the sentence so it's a different structure. Something like “We see revolutionary inventions daily.” It's concise and efficient.*

Are there other options?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus? If that doesn't give you a word you can use can you edit your question to mention what words you found and why they don't work?

Comment: "inventions are invented" is redundant. I would consider re-wording the sentence so it's a different structure. Something like "We see revolutionary inventions daily." It's concise and efficient.

Comment: Yep, consult a thesaurus for synonyms of "invent".

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Do you want to combine the two sentences into a single reworded version? Innovation and invention are not the same thing. Maybe you could reword the question from the beginning. I also thought you simply wanted an alternative word for "invented".

Answer (score 1):

> 1857   H. T. Buckle Hist. Civilisation Eng. I. xiv. 820   All half civilized nations have **made** many great inventions, but no great discoveries.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/98969?redirectedFrom=invention#eid)

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inventions+made%2Cinventions+patented%2Cinventions+devised&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinventions%20made%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinventions%20patented%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinventions%20devised%3B%2Cc0) shows 'made' is much more used than 'devised' but see below for the suggestion 'patented' which is, strangely, also not much used.

> Invention : The original contrivance or production of a new method or means of doing something, of an art, kind of instrument, etc. previously unknown

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/98969?redirectedFrom=invention#eid)

Inventions are made. Concepts are thought of, then, in the application of the concept into the real world, an invention is made. Strictly speaking it is only an invention when it is patented. So, the OP sentence could also be constructed as 'inventions are patented daily'.